# Javascript keyboard shortcuts not working (properly) in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Here is my code. With this code if I press CTRL+S, the default behaviour is running along with `Save()` function and same with `Open()`. This means `e.preventDefault()` not working.

But this works perfectly on chrome or ie10.
Another thing, if I remove my function from the events, and keep only `preventDefault()`, the default behaviour is stopped as it should.

Whats wrong with my code?

```
  document.onkeydown = function(e) {
      var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
      if (e.ctrlKey) {
        switch (key) {
          case 79: // Ctrl+O
            e.preventDefault();
            Open();
            break;
          case 83: // Ctrl+S
            e.preventDefault();
            Save();
            break;
        }
      }
    };
```

Comment: Where's your open/save function code?  With empty `Open` and `Save` functions, your code that you've given works.

Comment: yeah, they works perfectly on chrom or ie10
and also works when running from browser console.
even works on firefox but along with default behaviour.

Comment: Ah, you should have noted that... ;)  Default behaviour does not activate when using console to run code.  I'll try that again.

Comment: Works completely fine from my end (from local HTML file) - there must be something else that's wrong with your code/environment: the rest of it would be useful in solving the issue.

Comment: pls check it here - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92126558/projects/np/index.html
try pressing CTRL+S on firefox... and try the same on Chrome or IE.

Comment: Weird.  Try commenting out any the calls to `prompt` and `changeDocTitle`, and see if the save prompt loads.

Comment: yes it working! but why not working with those functions?